# GORM direct access to instance in a hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes CGroup and Directory, I would like to model a CGroup which has many Directories, however one of these many directories is known as the "root", and is directly accessible from the CGroup. Any CGroup should only ever have one root., and cascades should still work such that the deletion of any directory deletes all of its children.

Although wrong, this is what i have so far:

```
class CGroup{
    ...
    Directory root

    static hasMany = [directory:Directory]

    static constraints = {
        root(unique:true)
    }
}

class Directory {

    static hasMany = [children:Directory]
    ...
    static belongsTo = [parent:Directory,
                        cgroup:CGroup]

    static constraints = {
        parent nullable: true
    }
}
```

basically, i just need a reference to one instance from the "many" collection, stored in the "one" side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this a few different ways and the only way I could get it working was to allow `root` to be temporarily nullable. The problem I had without this was due to ordering - since `Directory` instances are in the `hasMany` they can't be saved until the `CGroup` is saved or the save() call will fail because `cgroup` is null (this is set when calling `addToDirectory`). But you can't save the CGroup without setting its `root` property if it's not nullable.

So I made `root` nullable but added a custom validator that fails validation if `root` is null and there are any instances in the `hasMany`:

```
static constraints = {
   root nullable: true, validator: { Directory root, CGroup cgroup ->
      if (!root && cgroup.directory?.size()) {
         return ['root.required']
      }
   }
}
```

So you would save the `CGroup` instance with any required values and without any associated `Directory` instances. Then attach the `Directory` instances with `addToDirectory` and set the `root` instance with the custom setter:

```
void setRoot(Directory root) {
   if (this.root) {
      removeFromDirectory this.root
   }

   if (root) {
      addToDirectory root
   }

   this.root = root
}
```

and save it again:

```
def group = new CGroup(...).save()

group.root = new Directory(...)
group.addToDirectory(new Directory(...))
group.addToDirectory(new Directory(...))
group.save()

g1.errors
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what i was looking for, the ordering problem you stated was the exact issue i faced but i wasn't so familiar with custom validators. Besides, i thought i may have been missing something obvious as it seemed like a fairly common scenario.
One thing, in your final block of code shouldn't the second addToDirectory actually be a call to setRoot? Cheers

Comment: No, root is set first and then there are two additional instances added for a total of 3. The order there doesn't matter as long as when you call save() the second time, root is set and that instance is in the hasMany, optionally along with some additional instances.